# cant use email as login cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I cant authenticate users when I login in appcontroller. I login with a non admin role and I still get through. . In fact I dont get any error and no debug value appears so the isAuthorized($user) doesnt work.l use the same code without email and used username in another website and it works fine. I looked at the code from the docs and really couldnt see the issue. The fields in the users table have role, email,password. Since the same code worked elsewhere without email for username then I am stuck on what to do as i checked how you add email as username in $components.

I have a user with a role called teacher that always logs in when it shouldnt and I have simple password enabled. I checked email and role values in database and all is as expected.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

```
 public $components = array(
     "Email",
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'  ),
          'authenticate' => array( 'Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'),
         'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line    
    )))
);


        public function isAuthorized($user) {
            // Admin can access every action
            debug($user['role']); //// NO output
            debug("asdddddddddddddddddddddddddd");//// NO output

            if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
                return true;
            }

            // Default deny
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: If you have DebugKit then check loggedIn User information..

Comment: I took out the line above  'authenticate' => array( 'Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password') to match  my working version. I cant even log in with any user now?

Comment: I have installed debugkit but I cant login anyway as shown above when I take out the authenticate line. This line isnt working in usercontroller  if  ($this->Auth->login()) so that shy I cant login

Comment: I solved the problem by getting rid of the email as the username and using username instead. This is the default value for cakephp and will cause the least amount of headaches